# Error on jasmine test with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

i'm creating a test for one of my directives and it was working fine, until i've added the following code so i could call a function when the user presses enter:

```
document.getElementById('selectableAdvancedValue').addEventListener('keydown',function(ev){
   if(ev.keyCode == 13 && ev.target.value.length > 0){
         scope.addQuery(scope.query);
   }
   scope.$apply();
 });
```

When i run the test again, it gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at GumgaAdvancedSearch.link (/home/igorsantana/gumga/gumga-framework-frontend/app/modules/gumga/directives/GumgaSearch/directives/GumgaAdvancedSearch.js:89:67)
    at $ (/home/igorsantana/gumga/gumga-framework-frontend/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:70:197)
    at B (/home/igorsantana/gumga/gumga-framework-frontend/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:59:255)
    at g (/home/igorsantana/gumga/gumga-framework-frontend/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:51:335)
    at /home/igorsantana/gumga/gumga-framework-frontend/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:50:444
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/igorsantana/gumga/gumga-framework-frontend/test/modules/gumga/directives/GumgaAdvancedSearchSpec.js:41:50)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (/home/igorsantana/gumga/gumga-framework-frontend/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:36:315)
    at Object.workFn (/home/igorsantana/gumga/gumga-framework-frontend/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2436:20)
Error: Declaration Location
    at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (/home/igorsantana/gumga/gumga-framework-frontend/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2407:25)
    at Suite.<anonymous> (/home/igorsantana/gumga/gumga-framework-frontend/test/modules/gumga/directives/GumgaAdvancedSearchSpec.js:35:24)
    at /home/igorsantana/gumga/gumga-framework-frontend/test/modules/gumga/directives/GumgaAdvancedSearchSpec.js:6:9
    at Object.context.execCb (/home/igorsantana/gumga/gumga-framework-frontend/node_modules/requirejs/require.js:1665:33)
    at Object.Module.check (/home/igorsantana/gumga/gumga-framework-frontend/node_modules/requirejs/require.js:874:51)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/igorsantana/gumga/gumga-framework-frontend/node_modules/requirejs/require.js:1121:34)
    at /home/igorsantana/gumga/gumga-framework-frontend/node_modules/requirejs/require.js:132:23
```

My code:
https://gist.github.com/opsigor/bafbf9d1843c77278ce8

Someone has an idea of how can i solve this? I'm new to Jasmine!

Answer (score 0):

The reason your test is failing is because you are either not properly setting up your test (creating the template and $compile it into the scope/templateCache) or it can not find the right reference to the document.

Either way, you need to use the `$document` [provider as a best practice](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window), as the reference is not the same as `window.document` in tests.

So use this:

```
$document.getElementById('selectableAdvancedValue')
.addEventListener('keydown',function(ev){
  if(ev.keyCode == 13 && ev.target.value.length > 0){
    scope.addQuery(scope.query);
  }
  scope.$apply();
});
```

Just a side note, if #selectableAdvancedValue is an input value, why not just use an [ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) and bind the change? The method you chose to take is against Angular best practices. This isn't jQuery, take advantage of it! [Take a look at common pitfalls](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq)